# Open Excel Files that Contains a Specific Date

Tags: excel, vba

In my folder, I have these files:

```
File1_010119, File2_010119, File3_030119, File4_050119, File5_050119
```

The current code I have opens all the excel files in the given directory. Is there a way to only open files that contains a specific date for example (010119)?

```
directory = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\BI\Assignment\Datasets\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
currentFile = "Main Excel File.xlsm"

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
```

Comment: What about `Dir(directory & "*010119.xl??")`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added your [Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57306967/11167163) to my post, hope it's good for you if no I will delete and let my own anser... Kindest regards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this :

```
directory = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\BI\Assignment\Datasets\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
currentFile = "Main Excel File.xlsm"

Do While fileName <> ""

If InStr(fileName, "010119") > 0 Then Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
```

or [pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C)'s solution is working to :

```
directory = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\BI\Assignment\Datasets\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*010119.xl??")
currentFile = "Main Excel File.xlsm"

Do While fileName <> ""

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
```

This way will browse only file with `010119.xl` in. And the way I propose you browse all `.xl` file then check the `fileName`

If you just want to browse file with `010119.xl` I would recommend you tu use the **second** way. And if you want to browse all file the **first**.

Comment: Just a note, the second solution should be faster than the `InStr` because it filters the files directly.

Comment: @CJSee  If this issue is solved May I ask you to accept this answer ? Click [here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)